# Apple magic track pad not working with 12.04.01

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, apple, magic-trackpad

I have just now finished installing Ubuntu 12.04.01 (Bye-bye Windows...). I am trying to get Apple magic track pad working with it. I have read several similar questions but no one answered my problem.

I believe bluetooth is detecting the trackpad image below

[image]

I tried toggling the Connection button but it again comes back to "OFF". I also tried resetting trackpad by pressing the power button.

Please suggest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to uninstall and reinstall bluez bluetooth package and it is working fine now.